# Animating UI Router using @keyframes not working

Tags: angularjs, css

I am attemping to animate the ui-router using @keyframes property.

What I want to achieve is that when the user clicks on an item in the menu, the page to come flying in

Doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
@keyframes page-slide {
  0%   {left:100%; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:75%; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:50%; top:0px;}
  75%  {left:25%; top:0px;}
  100% {left:0%; top:0px;}
}
```

Any clue what I could be missing here ?

Link to Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CXNaNogXwn8Vzg8rugDT?p=info

Comment: You have to be carefull your animation will have to be with the `ng-enter` class and `ng-leave` class. Look at this tutorial to better understand animation with angular : http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-nginclude-ngview-and-ngif

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working as expected?

If you want the animation to run more "fluidly" just define start and end:

```
@keyframes page-slide {
  from   {left:100%; top:0px;}
  to {left:0%; top:0px;}
}
```

Or using `translate3d`

```
@keyframes page-slide {
  from   {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Here a link to your example with the changes I made: http://embed.plnkr.co/7bTcKhLWJmm4hXkdcRvN/preview

Comment: or just shorten the `animation-duration: 300ms;` to achieve the *flying-in*

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna use CSS you need to wrap the `position:absolute` with a  `position:relative` container. Also set the `height: 100%` for all the containers.

http://embed.plnkr.co/xOEgPjvNtfpcQAxj6rWY/preview

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-transition {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: page-slide; 
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


@keyframes page-slide {
  0%   {left:100%; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:75%; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:50%; top:0px;}
  75%  {left:25%; top:0px;}
  100% {left:0%; top:0px;}
}
```